# Neo4jClient - difference between " .Where((TUser u) => u.Id == user.Id) " vs " .Where("u.Id = {param}").WithParam("param", user.Id) "

Tags: c#, neo4j, code-injection, neo4jclient

I Have a question about difference between using

```
db.Cypher.Match("(u:User)").Where((TUser u) => u.Id == user.Id)
```

vs

`db.Cypher.Match("(u:User)").Where("u.Id = {param}").WithParam("param", user.Id)`

Is there any security risk(injection) with first one, but I asked about performance differentiation, because It seems that checking query in the first one executed on web app process but in the second one it is executed by Neo4j Database Instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference.

In the first example, we automatically move it to a parameter for you: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#parameters

That parameter will be auto-named `p0`.

You can check this by looking in `QueryText` to see what's actually going over the wire: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#debugging

There is no injection risk in either of your examples. In both cases, the id is being handled safely. There would be injection risk if you did string concatenation, like `Where("u.Id = " + user.Id.ToString())`.

As for performance, until you call `.Results`, everything that you're writing is still getting packaged into the query and executed over on Neo4j. That `==` comparison is never actually executed in .NET: you're just using C# to express your query, before we then pull the expression tree apart and re-write it into Cypher for you.

Comment: Thanks @Tatham-Oddie , this means every where statement that use string pattern matching has injection risk and most implement by WithParam method ?